# Type casting (from derived class)

Tags: c++, class, casting, types

I want to make chain-calling like jquery-way in c++. The sample:

```
$('#obj').getParent().remove();
```

So, as I understand, each method of the class should return the pointer to himself (this).

Everything is okay until I call base-derived methods. The code:

```
class Base
{
   Base *base1() { return this; }
   Base *base2() { return this; }
};

class Derived : Base
{
   Derived *derived1() { return this; }
   Derived *derived2() { return this; }
};

Derived *obj = new Derived();
obj->derived1()->derived2(); // Everything is okay
obj->derived1()->base1()->derived2(); // Fail at second step
```

Sure, the **base1** returns the pointer for the Base. Are there any ways to make automatic casting?

---

**UPD:** Maybe that's possible with macros? Like

```
#define CORRECT_RETURN (this)
```

and

```
Base::base1() {
   return CORRECT_RETURN;
}
```

Something in this way. Or the compiler will not look at such construction?

Comment: That's not at all how the "jquery-way" functions.  Of course there is no way to do what you're trying to do.  The function you are trying to call on Base (after your call to base1()) must of course be within Base's interface.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.  If its is chaining calls together you can do that add infinite without using inheritance.  If the goal is to produce correctly typed returns you will need to look into covariance or overloading type casts.

Comment: The signature "base()" implies that you're getting a pointer to the base, which doesn't make a lot of sense.  The method names should be changed to match whatever function they serve, rather than simply being getters for the "this" pointer.  If you want the "this" pointer, simply skip the getters. You can still return "this" from any function, and use covariance (as Tyler suggested).

Comment: I doubt that `base1` and `base2` are really the names of the methods. They are most likely anonymized names that are just meant to indicate that it is a method is declared in the base class interface. So there should be no semantic problem with returning a pointer to a derived class object when the functions are called on a derived class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Override the `base1` and `base2` methods in `Derived` to change their return value from `Base*` to `Derived*`, e.g.

```
class Derived : Base
{
   Derived *base1() { return this; }
   Derived *base2() { return this; }
   Derived *derived1() { return this; }
   Derived *derived2() { return this; }
};
```

This is called *covariance* of return types and is legal in C++.

Assuming you want to actually use some functionality implemented in the base class methods without repeating it, you would do something like this:

```
class Derived : Base
{
   Derived *base1() { Base::base1(); return this; }
   Derived *base2() { Base::base2(); return this; }
   Derived *derived1() { return this; }
   Derived *derived2() { return this; }
};
```

Before you ask, no, you cannot create a situation where each derived class of the base automatically overrides the `base1` and `base2` methods using return types with the appropriate covariance. You have to do it manually every time, or else write a lot of scaffolding code to make it look like that's what's happening, which is usually more trouble than its worth.

Comment: don't forget virtual on base.  As defined, you're doing hiding, so you won't get polymorphism.

Comment: Virtual methods are probably a good idea with a hierarchy like this, but are not actually required here for this to work. `obj` is a `Derived*`, so `obj->derived1()` is a `Derived*`, so `obj->derived1()->base1()` calls `Derived::base1` (which actually returns a `Derived*`) whether or not `base1` is virtual.

Comment: @tyler-mchenry good answer. Could you look at update, please?

Comment: It's never going to be possible by modifying the base class, since there could be an infinite number of derived classes. Macros will not help you. If you don't want to use covariance, the only other answer is to just do a standard downcast: `dynamic_cast<Dervied*>(obj->derived1()->base1())->derived2()`, but I assumed you already knew about that and wanted something syntactically nicer.